# inner join not working in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have two tables in my database salaries model is Salary and userdetais model is Userdetail in which  i want to fetch result bye comparing id and user_id code is

```
$this->Salary->find('all',
  array(
      'joins'=>array(
      'table'=>'erp_userdetails',
      'alias' => 'Userdetail',
      'type' => 'INNER',
      'conditions' => array('Salary.user_id' => 'userdetail.id')
       )
     )
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
this->Salary->find('all',
            array('joins'=>
                    array(
                        array('table'=>'erp_userdetails',
                              'alias' => 'Userdetail',
                              'type' => 'INNER',
                              'conditions' => array('Salary.user_id' => 'userdetail.id')
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cakephp relational model.
Add belongsTo relation on Salary model

```
public $belongsTo=array(
    "Userdetail"=>array(
        "foreignKey"=>"user_id"
    )
)
```